# When to use storage queue on Azure?

Tags: azure

What is the difference between blob storage trigger and queue storage trigger?
Blob storage trigger sound like a queue to me. What are some examples that make sense for each?

Comment: You could check this [blog](https://www.sqlshack.com/different-azure-storage-types-file-blob-queue-table/).

Comment: Could you let me more about your scenario?

Comment: I want to use Azure Functions to execute a windows binary everytime a file is uploaded to the server and store the result somewhere.

For example user uploads a.jpg, Azure Functions executes "foo.exe a.jpg" and stores result.jpg somewhere. I'm confused about whether to use Blob or Queue storage.

Comment: `Azure Queue storage is a service for storing large numbers of messages that can be accessed from anywhere in the world via authenticated calls using HTTP or HTTPS. A single queue message can be up to 64 KB in size, and a queue can contain millions of messages, up to the total capacity limit of a storage account.`

Comment: According to your scenario, it seems blob is a more suitable choice.

Comment: So Queue storage is when you need to upload lots and lots of files?

Comment: Blob is more suitable for uploading multiple files scenario.

Comment: Is Blob the Azure equivalent to AWS S3?

Comment: Based on my understanding, they are equivalent. Please refer to this [link](http://www.ctera.com/company/blog/aws-s3-ia-vs-azure-cool-blob-comparison/).

Comment: So regular S3 is like hot Blob and S3-IA is like cold Blob?

Comment: Based on my understanding, I think you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between blob storage trigger and queue storage
>   trigger?

You could check this [blog](https://www.sqlshack.com/different-azure-storage-types-file-blob-queue-table/).

**Blob Storage**

The word blob is an acronym which stands for binary large object. Blobs typically include large files that are unstructured, such as images, video, music files, backup files etc.

Blob storage can be divided into two access tiers, a hot access tier for data which is accessed frequently and a cold access tier for data which is not accessed very often.

**Queue Storage**

Queue Storage is somewhat like MSMQ. It allows you to decouple your components and have reliable asynchronous communication. In Azure Queue Storage, the number of queues is only limited by the capacity of the storage account.

> I want to use Azure Functions to execute a windows binary everytime a
>   file is uploaded to the server and store the result somewhere. For
>   example user uploads a.jpg, Azure Functions executes "foo.exe a.jpg"
>   and stores result.jpg somewhere.

According to your scenario, it seems blob  is a more suitable choice.